# Rконсольная лексема DEBUG

Tags: c++

Всем привет! Пишу консольное приложение, у которого задана проверка лексемы DEBUG (#ifdef DEBUG). Как устанавливать эту лексему не в программе (#define DEBUG), а через консоль, перед запуском самой программы?
Пример:
C:/ТУТ ПУТЬ К ФАЙЛУ.EXE /DEBUG

Answer (score 2):

Никак. Директивы препроцессора существуют и обрабатываются лишь на этапе препроцессинга исходных кодов. Используйте аргументы командной строки.

Comment: Только в программе придётся ставить уже не `#ifdef DEBUG` а обычную проверку, поскольку иначе этого кода просто не будет

Comment: код разбухнет...